# LinkedList Swift Implementation

Tags: performance, linked-list, swift, complexity, collections

## Linked List Implementation in Swift

### Swift 5.0, Xcode 10.3

I have written an implementation for a doubly linked list in Swift. As well, I decided to make the node class private and thus hidden to the user so they don't ever need to interact with it. I have written all of the algorithms that I needed to give it `MutableCollection`, `BidirectionalCollection`, and `RandomAccessCollection` conformance.

---

### What I Could Use Help With

- I am pretty sure that my `LinkedList` type properly satisfies all of the time complexity requirements of certain algorithms and operations that come hand in hand with linked lists but am not sure.
- I was also wondering if there are any ways I can make my Linked List implementation more efficient.
- In addition, I am not sure if there are and linked list specific methods or computed properties that I have not included that I should implement.
- I have some testing but if you do find any errors/mistakes in my code that would help a lot.
- Any other input is also appreciated!

---

#### Here is my code:

```swift
public struct LinkedList<Element> {

    private var headNode: LinkedListNode<Element>?
    private var tailNode: LinkedListNode<Element>?
    public private(set) var count: Int = 0
    
    public init() { }
    
}

//MARK: - LinkedList Node
extension LinkedList {
    
    fileprivate typealias Node<T> = LinkedListNode<T>
    
    fileprivate class LinkedListNode<T> {
        public var value: T
        public var next: LinkedListNode<T>?
        public weak var previous: LinkedListNode<T>?
        
        public init(value: T) {
            self.value = value
        }
    }
    
}

//MARK: - Initializers
public extension LinkedList {
    
    private init(_ nodeChain: NodeChain<Element>?) {
        guard let chain = nodeChain else {
            return
        }
        headNode = chain.head
        tailNode = chain.tail
        count = chain.count
    }
    
    init<S>(_ sequence: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == Element {
        if let linkedList = sequence as? LinkedList<Element> {
            self = linkedList
        } else {
            self = LinkedList(NodeChain(of: sequence))
        }
    }
    
}

//MARK: NodeChain
extension LinkedList {
    private struct NodeChain<Element> {
        let head: Node<Element>!
        let tail: Node<Element>!
        private(set) var count: Int
        
        // Creates a chain of nodes from a sequence. Returns `nil` if the sequence is empty.
        init?<S>(of sequence: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == Element {
            var iterator = sequence.makeIterator()
            
            guard let firstValue = iterator.next() else {
                return nil
            }
            
            var currentNode = Node(value: firstValue)
            head = currentNode
            
            var nodeCount = 1

            while true {
                if let nextElement = iterator.next() {
                    let nextNode = Node(value: nextElement)
                    currentNode.next = nextNode
                    nextNode.previous = currentNode
                    currentNode = nextNode
                    nodeCount += 1
                } else {
                    tail = currentNode
                    count = nodeCount
                    return
                }
            }
            
            return nil
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Copy Nodes
extension LinkedList {
    private mutating func copyNodes() {
        guard let nodeChain = NodeChain(of: self) else {
            return
        }

        headNode = nodeChain.head
        tailNode = nodeChain.tail
    }
}


//MARK: - Computed Properties
public extension LinkedList {
    var head: Element? {
        return headNode?.value
    }
    
    var tail: Element? {
        return tailNode?.value
    }
    
    var first: Element? {
        return head
    }
    
    var last: Element? {
        return tail
    }
}

//MARK: - Sequence Conformance
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    
    public typealias Iterator = LinkedListIterator<Element>
    
    public __consuming func makeIterator() -> LinkedList<Element>.Iterator {
        return LinkedListIterator(node: headNode)
    }
    
    public struct LinkedListIterator<T>: IteratorProtocol {
        
        public typealias Element = T
        
        private var currentNode: LinkedListNode<T>?
        
        fileprivate init(node: LinkedListNode<T>?) {
            currentNode = node
        }
        
        public mutating func next() -> T? {
            guard let node = currentNode else {
                return nil
            }
            currentNode = node.next
            return node.value
        }
        
    }
}

//MARK: - Collection Conformance
extension LinkedList: Collection {
    
    public typealias Index = LinkedListIndex<Element>
    
    public var startIndex: LinkedList<Element>.Index {
        return Index(node: headNode, offset: 0)
    }
    
    public var endIndex: LinkedList<Element>.Index {
        return Index(node: nil, offset: count)
    }
    
    public func index(after i: LinkedList<Element>.Index) -> LinkedList<Element>.LinkedListIndex<Element> {
        precondition(i.offset != endIndex.offset, "LinkedList index is out of bounds")
        return Index(node: i.node?.next, offset: i.offset + 1)
    }
    
    public struct LinkedListIndex<T>: Comparable {
        fileprivate weak var node: LinkedList.Node<T>?
        fileprivate var offset: Int
        
        fileprivate init(node: LinkedList.Node<T>?, offset: Int) {
            self.node = node
            self.offset = offset
        }
        
        public static func ==<T>(lhs: LinkedListIndex<T>, rhs: LinkedListIndex<T>) -> Bool {
            return lhs.offset == rhs.offset
        }
        
        public static func < <T>(lhs: LinkedListIndex<T>, rhs: LinkedListIndex<T>) -> Bool {
            return lhs.offset < rhs.offset
        }
    }
    
}


//MARK: - MutableCollection Conformance
extension LinkedList: MutableCollection {
    
    public subscript(position: LinkedList<Element>.Index) -> Element {
        get {
            precondition(position.offset != endIndex.offset, "Index out of range")
            guard let node = position.node else {
                fatalError("LinkedList index is invalid")
            }
            return node.value
        }
        set {
            precondition(position.offset != endIndex.offset, "Index out of range")
            
            // Copy-on-write semantics for nodes
            if !isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&headNode) {
                copyNodes()
            }
            
            position.node?.value = newValue
        }
    }
}



//MARK: LinkedList Specific Operations
public extension LinkedList {
    
    mutating func prepend(_ newElement: Element) {
        replaceSubrange(startIndex..<startIndex, with: [newElement])
    }
    
    mutating func prepend<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == Element {
        replaceSubrange(startIndex..<startIndex, with: newElements)
    }
    
    mutating func popFirst() -> Element? {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        return removeFirst()
    }
    
    mutating func popLast() -> Element? {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        return removeLast()
    }
}

//MARK: - BidirectionalCollection Conformance
extension LinkedList: BidirectionalCollection {
    public func index(before i: LinkedList<Element>.LinkedListIndex<Element>) -> LinkedList<Element>.LinkedListIndex<Element> {
        precondition(i.offset != startIndex.offset, "LinkedList index is out of bounds")
        if i.offset == count {
            return Index(node: tailNode, offset: i.offset - 1)
        }
        return Index(node: i.node?.previous, offset: i.offset - 1)
    }
    
}

//MARK: - RangeReplaceableCollection Conformance
extension LinkedList: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    
    public mutating func replaceSubrange<S, R>(_ subrange: R, with newElements: __owned S) where S : Sequence, R : RangeExpression, LinkedList<Element>.Element == S.Element, LinkedList<Element>.Index == R.Bound {
        
        let range = subrange.relative(to: indices)
        
        precondition(range.lowerBound >= startIndex && range.upperBound <= endIndex, "Subrange bounds are out of range")
        
        // If range covers all elements and the new elements are a LinkedList then set references to it
        if range.lowerBound == startIndex, range.upperBound == endIndex, let linkedList = newElements as? LinkedList {
            self = linkedList
            return
        }
        
        var newElementsCount = 0
        
        // Update count after replacement
        defer {
            count = count - (range.upperBound.offset - range.lowerBound.offset) + newElementsCount
        }
        
        // There are no new elements, so range indicates deletion
        guard let nodeChain = NodeChain(of: newElements) else {
            
            // If there is nothing in the removal range
            // This also covers the case that the linked list is empty because this is the only possible range
            guard range.lowerBound != range.upperBound else {
                return
            }
            
            // Deletion range spans all elements
            guard !(range.lowerBound == startIndex && range.upperBound == endIndex) else {
                headNode = nil
                tailNode = nil
                return
            }
            
            // Copy-on-write semantics for nodes before mutation
            if !isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&headNode) {
                copyNodes()
            }

            // Move head up if deletion starts at start index
            if range.lowerBound == startIndex {
                // Can force unwrap node since the upperBound is not the end index
                headNode = range.upperBound.node!
                headNode!.previous = nil
                
            // Move tail back if deletion ends at end index
            } else if range.upperBound == endIndex {
                // Can force unwrap since lowerBound index must have an associated element
                tailNode = range.lowerBound.node!.previous
                tailNode!.next = nil
                
            // Deletion range is in the middle of the linked list
            } else {
                // Can force unwrap all bound nodes since they both must have elements
                range.upperBound.node!.previous = range.lowerBound.node!.previous
                range.lowerBound.node!.previous!.next = range.upperBound.node!

            }
            
            return
        }
        
        // Obtain the count of the new elements from the node chain composed from them
        newElementsCount = nodeChain.count
        
        // Replace entire content of list with new elements
        guard !(range.lowerBound == startIndex && range.upperBound == endIndex) else {
            headNode = nodeChain.head
            tailNode = nodeChain.tail
            return
        }
        
        // Copy-on-write semantics for nodes before mutation
        if !isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&headNode) {
            copyNodes()
        }
        
        // Prepending new elements
        guard range.upperBound != startIndex else {
            headNode?.previous = nodeChain.tail
            nodeChain.tail.next = headNode
            headNode = nodeChain.head
            return
        }
        
        // Appending new elements
        guard range.lowerBound != endIndex else {
            tailNode?.next = nodeChain.head
            nodeChain.head.previous = tailNode
            tailNode = nodeChain.tail
            return
        }
        
        if range.lowerBound == startIndex {
            headNode = nodeChain.head
        }
        if range.upperBound == endIndex {
            tailNode = nodeChain.tail
        }
        
        range.lowerBound.node!.previous!.next = nodeChain.head
        range.upperBound.node!.previous = nodeChain.tail
        
    }
    
}

//MARK: - ExpressibleByArrayLiteral Conformance
extension LinkedList: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    public typealias ArrayLiteralElement = Element
    
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: LinkedList<Element>.ArrayLiteralElement...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }
}

//MARK: - CustomStringConvertible Conformance
extension LinkedList: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "[" + lazy.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** My up-to-date `LinkedList` implementation can be found here: https://github.com/Wildchild9/LinkedList-Swift.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Thank you @Heslacher, I've added a link to the [Github repository](https://github.com/Wildchild9/LinkedList-Swift) where one can find my updated code and will leave the code in the question itself as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Nested types

All “dependent” types are defined within the scope of `LinkedList`, which is good. To reference those types from within `LinkedList` you don't have to prefix the outer type. For example,

```
public func index(before i: LinkedList<Element>.LinkedListIndex<Element>) -> LinkedList<Element>.LinkedListIndex<Element>
```

can be shortened to

```
public func index(before i: LinkedListIndex<Element>) -> LinkedListIndex<Element>
```

This applies at several places in your code.

#### Nested generics

There are several nested *generic* types:

```
fileprivate class LinkedListNode<T> 
private struct NodeChain<Element>
public struct LinkedListIterator<T>: IteratorProtocol
public struct LinkedListIndex<T>: Comparable
```

All these types are *only* used with the generic placeholder equal to the `Element` type of `LinkedList`, i.e.

```
private var headNode: LinkedListNode<Element>?
private var tailNode: LinkedListNode<Element>?

public typealias Iterator = LinkedListIterator<Element>
public typealias Index = LinkedListIndex<Element>
```

So these nested type do not need to be generic: They can simply use the `Element` type of `LinkedList`, i.e.

```
fileprivate class LinkedListNode {
    public var value: Element
    public var next: LinkedListNode?
    public weak var previous: LinkedListNode?

    public init(value: Element) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

which is then used as

```
private var headNode: LinkedListNode?
private var tailNode: LinkedListNode?
```

The same applies to the other nested generic types listed above. This allows to get rid of the distracting `<T>` placeholders and some type aliases. It becomes obvious that the same element type is used everywhere.

#### Another simplification

The `while true { ... }` loop in `NodeChain.init` is not nice for (at least) two reasons:

- A reader of the code has to scan the entire loop body in order to understand that (and when) the loop is eventually terminated.
- An artificial `return nil` is needed to make the code compile, but that statement is never reached.

Both problems are solved if we use a `while let` loop instead:

```
init?<S>(of sequence: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == Element {
   // ...

    while let nextElement = iterator.next() {
        let nextNode = LinkedListNode(value: nextElement)
        currentNode.next = nextNode
        nextNode.previous = currentNode
        currentNode = nextNode
        nodeCount += 1
    }
    tail = currentNode
    count = nodeCount
}
```

It also is not necessary to make the `head` and `node` properties of `NodeChain` implicitly unwrapped optionals (and does not make much sense for constant properties anyway). Simple non-optional constant properties will do:

```
    let head: Node<Element>
    let tail: Node<Element>
```

#### Structure

You have nicely structured the code by using separate extensions for the various protocol conformances.

In that spirit, `var first` should be defined with the `Collection` properties, and `var last` should be defined with the `BidirectionalCollection` properties.

#### To guard or not to guard

(This paragraph is surely opinion-based.) The `guard` statement was introduced to get rid of the “if-let pyramid of doom,” it allows to unwrap a variable without introducing another scope/indentation level.

The `guard` statement can be useful with other boolean conditions as well, to emphasize that some condition has to be satisfied, or otherwise the computation can not be continued.

But I am not a fan of using `guard` for every “early return” situation, in particular not if it makes the statement look like a double negation. As an example,

```
guard !(range.lowerBound == startIndex && range.upperBound == endIndex) else {
    headNode = nodeChain.head
    tailNode = nodeChain.tail
    return
}
```

is in my opinion much clearer written as

```
if range.lowerBound == startIndex && range.upperBound == endIndex {
    headNode = nodeChain.head
    tailNode = nodeChain.tail
    return
}
```

#### Performance

One issue that I noticed: You do not implement the `isEmpty` property, so that the default implementation for collection is used. As a consequence, each call to `isEmpty` creates two instances of `LinkedListIndex` (for `startIndex` and for `endIndex`), compares them, and then discards them. A dedicated

```
public var isEmpty: Bool { return count == 0 }
```

property would be more efficient.

#### A bug

There seems to be a problem with the copy-on-write semantics:

```
var l1 = LinkedList([1, 2, 3])
let l2 = l1
l1.removeFirst()
l1.removeLast()
```

makes the program abort with a “Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.”

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful analysis. I have gone through the nested types and shortened them all. In addition, I shortened the nested generic type names and made them use `LinkedList`'s `Element` type instead. I also rewrote my initializer using the clearer `while let ... {` loop. The `first` and `last` properties have now been properly organized. I also looked in and changed up the instances of `guard` that acted as a double negation. I added `@discardableResult` where fit. I also added in your implementation of `isEmpty`. Lastly, I think I have fixed the copy-on-write semantics finally 